# Ruby/Rails - How can I add items to an object with each loop iteration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, for-loop

I'm trying to figure ruby out a bit more.....

If I have an object

```
 @Trees =  Tree.find( :all )
```

Then make a loop where for each tree I find, add some apples...

```
 for tree in @trees   
     @apples = Apple.where(:tree_location = > tree.id )
 end
```

How can I add the additional apples found from each iteration of the loop to the initial object @apples ?

I tried

```
    @apples = @apples + Apple.where(:tree_location = > tree.id )
```

but got the error "can't convert Apple into Array"

Thanks for the help .... i'm on a cider deadline ***lol, corny i know***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all apples on all the trees, you should have a look at the following query:

```
@trees =  Tree.find( :all )
@apples = Apple.where(:tree_location => trees.map(&:id))
```

generates the following sql

```
select * from apples where tree_location in (... tree ids ...);
```

it will give you all the apples that belongs to the trees, and costs only two queries instead of n+1

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I get you, but...

```
trees =  Tree.find( :all )
apples = []
trees.each do |tree|
  apples << Apple.where(:tree_location = > tree.id ).to_a
end

apples = apples.flatten.uniq!

puts apples.inspect
```

Comment: `flatten` is because he's doing `to_a` on `Apple.where`, resulting in an array of arrays. It's not as effective as other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You might add "all" at the end:

```
@apples = @apples + Apple.where(:tree_location = > tree.id ).all
```